# Testing an alpha version of an Actions-on-Google project on my Anroid phone

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to test an alpha version of a dialogflow/google-actions on my Android phone, but Google Assistant don't open the opt-in link as expected (see screenshot below).

[image: Android screen after open the opt-in link on my phone]

What I did :

- I have created a project in Dialogflow, and activate the Google Assistant option inside Dialogflow
- I have configured the associated project on Actions-on-Google
- The "Simulator" works well and the "Testing on Device" option is activated
- The Alpha release has the "Deployed" status and my gmail email is in the alpha-testers list

But when I click on the opt-in link from my Android phone, it only opens a blank page which ask me to give a feedback on nothing (as shown in the screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

Two additional things to make sure you've done before Alpha testing:

1. Make sure you have the Google Home app installed on the phone you're testing with and that app is logged into the account you're inviting into Alpha.
2. Make sure you've allowed enough time - even in the "Deployed" state, it can still take a few hours to be available to everyone.